# Is there a way to use Android's "Nearby Share" with an Ubuntu computer?

Tags: android, sharing

Android phones (like Google Pixel phones and Samsung phones) have a feature called [Nearby Share](https://blog.google/products/android/nearby-share/). When sharing an item, you can select "Nearby" or "Nearby Share", and it will allow you to share an item to a nearby Android phone or ChromeOS device.

According to [Google's blog post](https://blog.google/products/android/nearby-share/), it uses these technologies:

> Nearby Share then automatically chooses the best protocol for fast and easy sharing using Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy, WebRTC or peer-to-peer WiFi — allowing you to share even when you’re fully offline.
>
> [image: Screenshot from blog post]

Is there a way to share using "Nearby Share" from an Android phone to an Ubuntu device, or vice-versa?

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you are asking, but you can try https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/ . It uses the Wireless network.

Comment: Maybe Canonical can help?! https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-send-file.html.en
(untested)

Comment: That seemed to work! I could share a file from my Ubuntu laptop to an Android phone with "Nearby Share" enabled. I don't know about the reverse, though.

Comment: @Michael If you post that as an answer, (with more than just a link but with instructions), I'll upvote the answer and accept it.

Comment: Right now is not a standard, is just a proprietary tool [which use](https://www.blog.google/products/android/better-together-nearby-share/) _a variety of connection technologies, including Bluetooth, WiFi, NFC, UWB and WebRTC, to automatically find an efficient way for your friend to send you the photo, even if you’re not online._ For the time being the best solution is [GSConnect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/)/KDEConnect

Comment: @PabloBianchi yes sure its not a standard, but neither is (gs/kde)connect, but what's more important is its not "proprietary" in any meaning I know of, as Google makes the code available for "nearby" under the Apache License: https://github.com/google/nearby which is far *less* restrictive than the GPL that GSconnect uses for example.

Answer (score 5):

The code for Nearby is [available from Google under a open source  license](https://github.com/google/nearby).

In a quick search, despite a [Linux build being supported](https://github.com/google/nearby/tree/main/connections), it unfortunately looks like no one has yet packaged it up in a nice easy to use fashion for Ubuntu yet.

Comment: > NOTE: Linux has no mediums implemented.

Looks like it's more than just a packaging issue. Someone would have to write a backend for it.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest that I have been able to find so far, is a work-in-progress project CrossDrop

https://github.com/PlutoHDDev/CrossDrop

> **CrossDrop** is a partial implementation of Google's Nearby Share in Flutter for macOS, iOS and Linux.
>
> **Note:**
> At the moment I don't have the time to work on implementing Nearby Share here, even though that's what it's all about. I've started working on it, but I don't have the time to finish it at the moment.
>
> The app lives in your menu bar and saves files to your downloads folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try Warpinator. You can share files and folders. It has an app in the play store as well as the app store.
[Link to Warpinator](https://github.com/linuxmint/warpinator)

Comment: Is this compatible with "Nearby Share" for Android? Or is it an alternative to it?

Comment: @Flimm It's an alternative to it and a pretty good one. You can send and receive folder structures as well. And, it's pretty fast.

Comment: This only works if the two devices are on the same LAN (on Wi-Fi or Ethernet). "Nearby Share" works when two devices are near each other, even if they are not on the same LAN.